# how redirect user with stripe react component and django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I would like to redirect my user after he has made a payment (successful or failed) to a page automatically.

Currently, the payment is going well, the update is a success on stripe and I manage to retrieve the necessary information with my django view.

However, after successful payment, no redirection takes place. There are several documentation but I can't find a way to do it with the react component proposed by stripe themselves.

How can I proceed?

here is my work

**Offers.js** : ReactComponent by Stripe

```
<stripe-pricing-table 
   pricing-table-id="prctbl_<my_pricing_table_key>"
   publishable-key="pk_test_<my-stripe-public-key>"
   // user informations for update subscriptions django model
   customer-email={`${info_user.info_user.email}`}
   client-reference-id={`${info_user.info_user.id}`}
 >
 </stripe-pricing-table>
```

When I click on the subscribe button, everything is fine. the payment is made on stripe and I retrieve the information in my webhook with django

**views.py**

```
class StripeWebhookView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    helpers = AbonnementHelpers
    updating = UpdateAbonnementHelpers
    
    def post(self, request):
        payload = request.body
        sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
        endpoint_secret = STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
        # webhook
        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
            )
        except ValueError as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # full session data recovery
        if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
            info_event = self.helpers().stripe_event(event)
            user = UserAccount.objects.get(id=info_event['user_id'])
            # check if user subscription exist in my database
            try:
                abo = Abonnement.objects.get(user=user)
                self.updating.update_abo(
                    abo=abo,
                    subscription_id=info_event['subscription_id'],
                    num_facture=info_event['num_facture'],
                    is_paid=info_event['is_paid'],
                    expire_at=info_event['expire_at'],
                    price=info_event['price'],
                    abo_id=info_event['abonnement_id'],
                    customer_id=info_event['customer_id'],
                    plan=info_event['plan']
                )
            # if not exist, create the subscription with django model
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                abo = Abonnement(
                    user=user,
                    email=user.email,
                    stripe_subscription_id=info_event['subscription_id'],
                    numero_facture=info_event['num_facture'],
                    is_paid=info_event['is_paid'],
                    abonne_jusquau=info_event['expire_at'],
                    price=info_event['price'],
                    abonnement_id=info_event['abonnement_id'],
                    stripe_user_id=info_event['customer_id'],
                    plan=info_event['plan']
                )
                abo.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# here i try several things but not working currently (with redirect)
class SuccessView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return redirect('/success')


class CancelView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'cancel.html', {})
```

And here are my affiliate url routes to my subscriptions app

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # it's ok !
    path('stripe-webhook', views.StripeWebhookView.as_view(), name='create-payment-intent'),
    # not use currently
    path('success', views.SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
    path('cancel', views.CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Abonnement(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paye_le = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    abonne_jusquau = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0, blank=True)
    numero_facture = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    abonnement_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripe_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} {self.plan}"
```

after the payment I get a page with "successful payment" but no redirect to apply and no possibility to return to the application. the URL looks like this:
[https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_b1m[...]ERl#fid[...]ICUl](https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_b1m%5B...%5DERl#fid%5B...%5DICUl)

***[...] = sequence of several numbers and letters***

what am I doing wrong? thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set up redirection to your application after successful payment, it can be done by setting in the [pricing table page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/pricing-tables) in Dashboard. You can select `Don't show confirmation page` in every price to disable showing Stripe's confirmation page and set the return URL to direct to your website.

Here's the screenshot of where you can set it up:

[image]

Comment: I forgoted,
« Simple is better than complexe »

Thanks for your answer